# What does it mean: carrying the stably integrated gene

Tags: genetics

Reading this study
http://www.nature.com/cr/journal/v23/n10/full/cr2013122a.html

They writing

> Multiple **exogenous** and endogenous genes can be simultaneously activated
>   by CRISPR-on
>
> We tested single, double and triple activation of a TetO::tdTomato
>   transgene and the endogenous SOX2 and IL1RN genes (Figure 3A) in
>   HEK293T cells carrying the stably integrated TetO::tdTomato transgene

Could you please help me to understand: They talking about exogenous gene. But saying "carrying the stably integrated". Does that mean that this gene (TetO::tdTomato) is in the cell genome (integrated to genome)? If so, what is the meaning of exogenous here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster, an exogeneous gene is defined as " introduced from or produced outside the organism or system; specifically :  not synthesized within the organism or system—compare endogenous".

I believe they refer to the tetO::tdTomato transgene as an exogeneous, or not originating from the species of study

Comment: Yes thats what I am understanding from this too. Thank you.

Comment: @Barbos if this answered your question, please consider [accepting](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the check mark to turn it green.